# Using "that" in place of "it" as an object is not always correct. How can I explain why?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

A student wrote to me

> I'm sorry I was absent for class on Monday. What is the homework? I want to do that before the next class.

I prefer using *it* to *that* but am not sure what explanation I should give. Can you help?

Comment: Hi. Is there a question mark missing after homework? That would clarify your question.

Comment: Yes. Mea culpa! I miss-typed. There should be a question mark after homework.

Answer (score 8):

Neither *that* nor *it* is grammatical in that position. In fact, what is grammatical is no word at all:

> I'm sorry I was absent for class on Monday. What is the homework I want to do before the next class?

Unless of course you meant this, in which case you do need *it*:

> I'm sorry I was absent for class on Monday. What is the homework? I want to do it before the next class.

Comment: Looking at your first answer, don't you mean "What is the homework I should do/have to do before the next class?" Not "want to do"?

Comment: The quoted text is what the student wrote. I doubt the student asks _What is the homework I want to do?_

Comment: Actually, *that* would work just as well in your second example. "What is the homework? I want to do that before the next class."

Comment: @Robusto: I don't find "that" to be wrong, but I do find "it" to be better.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I think it depends on context. If the speaker wished to stress the pronoun for some reason — emphasis, specificity (as in a list of things which might be competing for his attention), sarcasm, whatever — *that* might turn out to be the perfect choice.

Comment: @Robusto: Certainly, it does depend on context. Sometimes these kinds of demonstrative and pronoun judgments are so difficult to justify and analyze, and yet they are so easy and intuitive to use, as a native speaker. It's fascinating.

Comment: I think the OP was looking for an explanation why "it" is preferable to "that".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it should read

> I'm sorry I was absent for class on Monday. What is the homework? I want to do it before the next class.

as @nohat suggested, I think the reason I'd prefer "it" is, "that" is a demonstrative pronoun, and the antecedent (the homework) is very clear from the previous statement. There is no need to use "that" to emphasize what it is the speaker wants to do.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My original quote should have had a question mark after "homework". Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

> What homework should/must I do before the
>   next class?

Regardless of your student's somewhat faulty  grasp of English, you should rejoice that you have such a polite and conscientious student. Let's hope he or she goes far. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, your intuition that "it" is better than "that" is correct. Here is how I would explain why:

The word "it" is a neutral pronoun, simply referring back to a previously mentioned concept (in this case, the homework). The word "that" is a demonstrative pronoun (carrying with it a sense of pointing something out - either literally or figuratively), and one that carries a sense of distance from the speaker (especially when compared with "this").

Thus, "that" is preferable when:

- Something is literally being pointed out ("I want *that*!")
- Reference is made (perhaps implicitly) to a specific thing among alternatives ("I want to do *that* before the next class (even if I don't do the reading and other preparation that I'm supposed to)"). Compare "I didn't want to do it", which refers simply to a choice between doing the action or not, to "I didn't want to do *that*", which implies that I did want to do *something*.
- There is a desire to distance the object from the speaker ("Did you have to bring *that* in here?")

Since (presumably) none of the above applies in your example, the more neutral "it" fits better.